# I can't access scrapyd port 6800 from browser

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapyd

I searched a lot on this, it may have a simple solution that I am missing.

I have setup scrapy + scrapyd on both my local machine and my server. They work both ok when I try as "scrapyd".

I can deploy to local without a problem, and I can access to localhost:6800 as well from the browser and I can run spiders on local.

After running scrapyd on remote, I try to deploy to http://remoteip:6800/ with the same as I did deploy locally,

I get,

```
Packing version 1500333306
Deploying to project "projectX" in http://remoteip:6800/addversion.json
Deploy failed: <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
```

I also can't access http://remoteip:6800/ from my local PC, but I can access from ssh on remote PC (with curl)

I opened inbound and outbound connections on the remote server, what else I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First check if its running or not, run curl `localhost:6800` on the server where ScrapyD is running

Check if firewall is enabled

```
sudo ufw status
```

Ideally, just allow tcp connections to 6800instead of disabling firewall, to do so

```
sudo ufw allow 6800/tcp
sudo ufw reload
```

Check your `scrapyd.conf` please set

```
bind_address=0.0.0.0
```

instead of

```
bind_address=127.x.x.x
```

`0.0.0.0` will make scrapyD accessible for incoming connections outside the server/instance, not only localhost.

Then stop scrapyD, I do `killall scrapyd` to stop scrapyd

Then restart scrapyD using command `scrapyd`

---

**Note:**
If you want to keep `scrapyd` running even after you disconnect from server, do this

```
nohup scrapyd >& /dev/null &
```

---

**Also see my answer to [set ScrapyD as a System Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47067997/4094231)**

Comment: spent the last 8 hours on this and bind_address=0.0.0.0 was the answer.  Thanks!

Comment: This is especially helpful for Docker deployments. I tried everything to get scrapyd to serve its admin page inside a Docker container while it worked fine on my host system. Creating a config file and using bind_address=0.0.0.0 solved it. Here's an example config setting: https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config.html

Answer (score 0):

*I know this answer may be late, but I hope it can help others like me.*

From the official [documentation](https://scrapyd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config.html), it will search the config file in these places:

- /etc/scrapyd/scrapyd.conf (Unix)
- c:\scrapyd\scrapyd.conf (Windows)
- /etc/scrapyd/conf.d/* (in alphabetical order, Unix) scrapyd.conf
- ~/.scrapyd.conf (users home directory)

So you need to create a `scrapyd.conf` file, and put some configurations in it.

Here is an example configuration file with all the defaults from the the documentation:

```
[scrapyd]
eggs_dir    = eggs
logs_dir    = logs
items_dir   =
jobs_to_keep = 5
dbs_dir     = dbs
max_proc    = 0
max_proc_per_cpu = 4
finished_to_keep = 100
poll_interval = 5.0
bind_address = 127.0.0.1
http_port   = 6800
debug       = off
runner      = scrapyd.runner
application = scrapyd.app.application
launcher    = scrapyd.launcher.Launcher
webroot     = scrapyd.website.Root

[services]
schedule.json     = scrapyd.webservice.Schedule
cancel.json       = scrapyd.webservice.Cancel
addversion.json   = scrapyd.webservice.AddVersion
listprojects.json = scrapyd.webservice.ListProjects
listversions.json = scrapyd.webservice.ListVersions
listspiders.json  = scrapyd.webservice.ListSpiders
delproject.json   = scrapyd.webservice.DeleteProject
delversion.json   = scrapyd.webservice.DeleteVersion
listjobs.json     = scrapyd.webservice.ListJobs
daemonstatus.json = scrapyd.webservice.DaemonStatus
```

And what you need to do is: **change the bind_address to 0.0.0.0**